# How to acess HttpServletRequest in Jaas login module in Tomcat

Tags: java, websphere, tomcat7, servlet-filters, jaas

We have a task to certify our application in Tomcat7 which is already certified and running in Websphere.

Our application in websphere has JAAS custom login module and it access HttpServletRequest object via callback handlers as shown below and we set user related information in the session object (which is retrieved from request).

```
javax.security.auth.callback.Callback callbacks[] = new javax.security.auth.callback.Callback[3];
callbacks[0] = new javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback(
            "Username: ");
callbacks[1] = new javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback(
            "Password: ", false);
callbacks[2] = new com.ibm.wsspi.security.auth.callback.WSServletRequestCallback(
            "HttpServletRequest: ");
```

The problem here is that, as you see, the above code is specific to websphere. So, we want to write another custom login module specific to Tomcat. Excuse me, this is designed by someone else.

**Now the queustion is how can I access HttpServletRequest/HttpSession object in Jaas login module in Tomcat?**

Note: I have tried to use ThreadLocal to pass the user information instead HttpServeletRequest but it appears that it is not advised since threads are reused from Thread Pool in Tomcat and there could be a potential problems (memory leak, user information shared etc) in case if we don't clear the ThreadLocal properly.

Comment: Comparing to WAS Tomcat has very limited options when it comes to JAAS. Quite likely you will need to change the application. Is there anything that prevents populating session object in servlet filter?

Comment: JAAS login module is executed before servlet filter. Only JAAS login module is aware of authentication/authorization information such as invalid credentials, account locked, password expired, access prohibited and more. I would need this information to show appropriate error message if login is failed.

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution after 1 year :)

Answer (score 2):

In Jboss, it can be get through:

```
HttpServletRequest  request = (HttpServletRequest) PolicyContext
                        .getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
```

But PolicyContext is in JACC and Tomcat does not support JACC yet. It might be supported in Tomcat 9, but low on Tomcat's priority.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to obtain the HttpServletRequest in the LoginModule. The LoginModule is the JAAS version of an identity store, which is a database/repository for users, their credentials and optionally groups or roles.

In Tomcat a LoginModule is not the prime identity store type. A Realm is, but Tomcat provides a bridge so you can use a LoginModule anyway. But as you have discovered the usage of JAAS in Java EE is not standard. Servers either don't use JAAS at all, or they use it differently from any other server.

What you're looking for is the *authentication mechanism*, which is the thing responsible for interacting with the request, response and session. Tomcat has two interfaces for that, one is Tomcat specific, the other is a Java EE standard.

1. The *Authenticator* see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/package-summary.html
2. The *ServerAuthModule* see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/jaspic.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/security/auth/message/module/ServerAuthModule.html